# $FUNCNAME alternative in /bin/sh

Tags: shell, sh

Does the POSIX shell have something similar to [`$FUNCNAME`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835943) in [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/bash.html)   ?

Comment: Asking this because I normally use `do_something() { func=${FUNCNAME:-do_something} .... ; }` in my portable scripts and I was wondering if there is a simpler way maybe...

Comment: Dup http://stackoverflow.com/q/2630812

Comment: Not really, the question there is '_The question: how do I get a list of all function names in a script from inside the script?_' not 'What is the current function name'. I am looking for a solution which looks like in bash `echo "Usage $FUNCNAME <filename>".`

Comment: Not that I know of. I think that's why bash added `$FUNCNAME` and I believe zsh uses `$0`.

Comment: This Bourne Shell? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell . or the Bourne Again shell, more commonly known as `bash`? Good luck.

Comment: Lol, thanks for the heads up, completely forgot about this stuff. Corrected the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.** The list of variables which are required to have special behavior by the POSIX sh standard [is quite small](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_05_03), and no equivalent to `FUNCNAME` is given; the closest thing is `LINENO`.

(If such a thing already existed in POSIX sh, why would bash have added its own rather than implementing the specification?)

Comment: That was the question really: is it a bash specific stuff or do I miss something? Thanks for the answer

Comment: @AndrasP It's bash specific.  Ksh93 has an equivalent in `${.sh.fun}`.  Try `function a { echo ".sh.fun=${.sh.fun}"; }`.  You can make it emulate bash with `typeset -n FUNCNAME=.sh.fun`.  By default, ksh tries not to overload shell variables with special behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Just a note on how I tested if there is a variable that tells me what the current function is. What was confusing originally is `FUNCNAME` is available on Mac even in `/bin/sh` so I was wondering why it was empty on Linux - hence the OP.
Opening the spec at [variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) shed some light on it (see accepted answer), but I was still curious what else is available in functions.

*How to see the function related <strike>environment</strike> shell variables:*

> set shall write the names and values of *all shell variables* in the collation sequence of the current locale

So

```
$ set > a

$ function f() {
    set > b
}

$ f
```

Then

```
diff a b
```

Will give me function related variables in bash (and nothing in sh as expected)

```
> BASH_LINENO=([0]="5")
14a15
> FUNCNAME=([0]="f")
55c56
```

Comment: As the POSIX spec. quotation shows, `set` without arguments should list _variables only_.
It is a `bash`-specific _extension_ to also list _functions_ (If you run `bash` in POSIX mode (e.g., by running `shopt -so posix`), you'll get only variables). If using `bash` were an option, you could simply use `$FUNCNAME`.
Truthfully, this answer is primarily a distraction - consider accepting @CharlesDuffy's answer.
As an aside: the 'variables' link is about _environment_ variables, not _shell_ variables.

Comment: This was more of a side note on how can you find a variable that is related to the **current function**. Originally I was looking for a variable, so obviously I am using `set`.

Comment: If this is a side note, please update this answer to clearly label it as such, and _explain how it relates to your question_. Also, the sentence "This also means that if I do the following I should get the information I needed" is especially confusing, given that the quote directly above clearly talks about shell _variables_ only. What I do find interesting is that you're implicitly demonstrating that POSIX-like shells do not create functions and variables until the line they're defined on is encountered during execution.

Comment: Thanks mklement0, this was is not really in context indeed, clarified.

Comment: `/bin/sh` on many versions of MacOS is actually provided by bash (which runs in POSIX mode when so invoked, and so behaves *slightly* different from its original version, but is still a large superset). Testing its behavior doesn't tell you much.

Comment: `strings /bin/sh` is your friend, by the way, if you're looking for clues about who a specific implementation is / where it comes from.

Comment: `sh-3.2$ echo $SHELL`
`/bin/bash`

Yeah, that's true, I just _assumed_ I was in sh... Writing portable scripts make a whole different experience. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: `$SHELL` just tells you what your _default_ shell is - irrespective of what shell you happen to be running at that time, so `echo $SHELL` doesn't tell you what you think it does. On some platforms, `sh` is just a _symlink_ to `bash`, but on OS X it is actually a _separate executable_ (still `bash` in drag, but with a few changes hard-compiled); once you've ruled out a simple symlink, `strings /bin/sh` is your friend, as @CharlesDuffy has stated.

Comment: _Environment_ variables aren't the same as _shell_ variables: all environment variables (which are independent of the shell) are also exposed as shell variables, but not all shell variables are also environment variables (they need to be _exported_ (`export`) for that).

Comment: There is no such thing as "function-related variables" in Bash; `set` also lists shell _functions_ (their full definitions) by default, which is an _extension_ to the POSIX standard. As a side-effect of Bash's execution model, functions  only show up in the output of `set` once their _definition_ has been executed in the flow of normal execution, which is right after `f()`'s closing brace, actually (irrespective of whether `f` is later _called_ or not).

Comment: The lesson here is: if you target `sh`, assume POSIX features only - that's the only common denominator across platforms.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for your extremely useful comments