# Get a list of functions in a POSIX shell script

Tags: function, sh, posix

I am looking for a solution like what is posted in the following question:

[Get a list of function names in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630812/get-a-list-of-function-names-in-a-shell-script)

But which works in a POSIX shell script. And if it is not possible, then at least something that works in dash.

I have the same scenario as him: I am making a help screen for a script whose first argument is a function and succeeding arguments are parameters of that function.

Since the script is under active development, I want the help screen to be automatically updated whenever I add a new "command" under the script.

Some functions are internal, and I solved that by putting a pattern in the function name if it is callable as a command from the script. Once I get the list of functions in my script it would be simple to grep out the ones containing that pattern so I can list them in the help screen.

Comment: If it's all within your script then the `grep "()"` from the duplicate should work, perhaps with some cleanup processing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, since the "function" keyword mentioned in the duplicate is not allowed in dash and everyone in that question was assuming bash. I tried it and it almost works. How do I get rid of grep grepping itself? The line containing `grep "()"` also shows up in the search for `()`.

Comment: The standard trick is to use a regex which doesn't match itself, like `grep '[(])'`