# How to get awk print function name and comment

Tags: bash, awk

Hello awk ninjas I need some help, so I found a solution to print defined function names from my shell script from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630812/get-a-list-of-function-names-in-a-shell-script) but my issue I would love my functions to show the comments... here is an example of how my functions are defined.

```
function1() { # this is a function 1
          command1
        }

function2() { # this is a function 2
          command2
        }

function3() { # this is a function 3
          command3
        }
```

So the command provided that works is this one: `typeset -f | awk '/ \(\) $/ && !/^main / {print $1}'` and the output will be this:

```
function1
function2
function3
```

But I would love the output to be this way (a 4 space between the function name and comment would be really nice also):

```
function1    # this is a function 1
function2    # this is a function 2
function3    # this is a function 3
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid that comments are not stored together with function definition.

Comment: What about assigning the comment to a dummy variable, like:
`function1() { __COMMENT="this is a function 1" [...]` ?

Comment: and then how will I view the comment ??

Comment: once assigned to a variable

Comment: It seems that bash drops the comments when it interprets the function definition. If you want them, you'll need to parse the source file they are defined in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace each `#` with `:`:

```
function1() { : this is a function 1
          command1
        }

function2() { : this is a function 2
          command2
        }

function3() { : this is a function 3
          command3
        }
```

```
$ typeset -f | awk '/ \() $/{fn=$1} /^ *:/{ print fn $0 }'
function1    : this is a function 1;
function2    : this is a function 2;
function3    : this is a function 3;
```

Change the awk script as you like to match whatever other function layouts you have and/or tweak the output however you prefer.

See [What is the purpose of the : (colon) GNU Bash builtin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3224878/1745001) for more info.

Comment: Damn this is clean and easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

*Writing as an answer to have better formatting capabilities.*
You could try to use a custom, "dummy" variable and store a comment in it.

Let's declare our function:

```
test_function () {
  __COMMENT="TEST_FUNCTION"
}
```

I used `__COMMENT` variable as our placeholder. Notice, that `bash` will print the function name and the variable in 2 lines, so we have to use a state machine in our `awk` code:

```
typeset -f | awk \
'match($0, /__COMMENT="[^"]*/) {
    if (functionname) {
        print functionname ": " substr($0, RSTART+11, RLENGTH-11)
    }
}

/ \(\) {$/ && !/^main / {functionname=$1}'
```

From the end:

```
/ \(\) {$/ && !/^main / {functionname=$1}
```

**I had to modify Your patter to match my output, so You may need to remove the brace character to make it work on Your side.** It will look for a function declaration and store its name as `functionname`.

```
'match($0, /__COMMENT="[^"]*/) {
```

It will look for our variable. Notice, that the length of `__COMMENT="` is `11`. We will need it.

```
if (functionname) {
    print functionname ": " substr($0, RSTART+11, RLENGTH-11)
}
```

If `functionname` is set it prints the name and a substring of our match skipping 11 characters from the beginning and 1 from the end (quotes).

Comment: Hey so I removed the curly brace character and it works but it showing me an error: `awk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp escape sequence \`\"' is not a known regexp operator` how can I fix that bit.

Comment: Try to remove backslash before quote marks. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send your output through this pipeline:

```
grep '() ' | grep -v '^main' | sed '/() { /s//    /'
```

Explanation: the first `grep` finds all the lines containing a function definition with `()` . The second one filters out the `main()` function. Finally, the `sed` command replaces the string `() {`  by four spaces.

For testing purpose, I put the input you described above into a file `s.txt` containing:

```
function1() { # this is a function 1
          command1
        }

function2() { # this is a function 2
          command2
        }

function3() { # this is a function 3
          command3
        }

main() { # this is the main function
          commands
        }
```

when I run

```
cat s.txt | grep '() ' | grep -v '^main' | sed '/() { /s//    /'
```

I get this output:

```
function1    # this is a function 1
function2    # this is a function 2
function3    # this is a function 3
```

Comment: this doesn't work.

Comment: @n00b: I will edit my answer so that you can see what is working on my configuration.

Comment: @n00b: What do you mean with "this doesn't work"? Which output do you get?

Comment: The thing is it should be able to get the functions defined in the script the command is running within.

Comment: @n00b, so maybe the script could use `cat` on itself, like `cat $0`?